# Disable International Countries Dropdown in Shipping Quote within Shopping Cart

Tags: cart, magento-1.6, shopping-cart

I am managing a website that needs to disable international shipping. I have done this in the admin and the options are gone from checkout but within the cart there is a place to get a shipping quote and it is still showing the dropdown of all the international locations. Can anyone point me to where in the admin I can disable the shipping quote for international locales? I have turned off all countries but the United States in System > Configuration > Sales > Shipping Methods but the countries are all showing in the shipping quote drowpdown: http://minnewyork.com/checkout/cart/

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

if you can find the name of that block from respective xml file and you can remove that block by name adding the folloing code in your themes local.cml file like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>
    <default>
        <remove name="nameofblockfromxml" />
    </default>
</layout>
```

Comment: Thank you. I will go to my developer with this if I have to, but am hoping this is something I can manage in the admin because I will eventually need to turn it back on.